# Can I export functions of a static library when building a dynamic library linking against that static library?

Tags: c++, static-libraries, dynamic-library

On win32, I built a dynamic library called **A.dll** which linked against a static library called **B.lib**, and also built a executable called **C.exe** which **only** dependent on **A.dll**.

But now, in **C.exe** if I want use a function **foo** which only has definition in **B.lib**, I have to link **C.exe** against **B.lib** again.

The question is can I export **foo** from **B.lib** directly into **A.dll** when building **A.dll**, and how?

Also I want to know what will it be when dealing with GCC.

Comment: Just include header in your application and say linker to use **B.lib**

Comment: Add a function in A.dll that calls B.lib's foo().  The possibilities are endless

Comment: Why I still need B.lib if A.dll contains foo() symbol? Because I have already linked A,dll against to B.lib.@teivaz

Comment: Yes, this maybe a solution, but can't be the best. In my opinion, that would loose some performance cause additional function call.@MichaëlRoy

Comment: The linker does not know that it needs to include the function in the final executable file.  And it doesn't know that it needs to be exported.  The most basic solution is to use a .def file.  #pragma comment(linker, "/export:foo") is a way to do it in source code.

Comment: The linker will know as long as I have a foo reference in A.dll.@HansPassant

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A function `foo` can be exported from a DLL provided that:-

- You declare `foo` with the `__declspec(dllexport)` attribute when you
  compile the function into an object file, say `foo.obj`
- You link `foo.obj` into the DLL.

It doesn't matter how `foo.obj` gets linked into the DLL.

Maybe you specify `foo.obj` explicitly in the linkage of the DLL.

Maybe you've put `foo.obj` is inside a static library, say `foobar.lib`, and the linkage
of the DLL contains some reference to the function `foo`. Then the linker will
extract `foo.obj` from the `foobar.lib` and link it into the DLL, to resolve
that reference.

If `foo.obj` is linked by being extracted from a static library, the linkage
is exactly the same as if `foo.obj` was linked by name. A static library is simply
a bag of object files from which the linker can pick the ones it needs carry
on the linkage. When the linkage is done, the program or DLL produced has no dependency
on a static library. If it needed any object files in the bag, it has got them now. It doesn't need the bag.

Here's a illustration using the GCC mingw-w64 toolchain for Windows of how a
DLL-exported function is linked from within a static library:

```
C:\mingw-w64\x86_64-7.2.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0>echo off
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>cd develop\so\scrap
C:\develop\so\scrap>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 16C7-F955

 Directory of C:\develop\so\scrap

16/12/2017  17:50    <DIR>          .
16/12/2017  17:50    <DIR>          ..
16/12/2017  12:41               116 greeting.cpp
16/12/2017  12:42                99 greeting.h
16/12/2017  12:10               109 hello.cpp
16/12/2017  12:12                90 hello.h
16/12/2017  16:21               197 main.cpp
16/12/2017  12:25               117 niceday.cpp
16/12/2017  12:26                96 niceday.h
               7 File(s)            824 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  101,878,943,744 bytes free
```

**hello.cpp**

```
#include "hello.h"
#include <iostream>

void hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

**hello.h**

```
#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

extern __declspec(dllexport) void hello();

#endif
```

We'll compile `hello.cpp`:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>g++ -Wall -c -o hello.obj hello.cpp
```

Similarly:

**niceday.cpp**

```
#include "niceday.h"
#include <iostream>

void niceday()
{
    std::cout << "What a nice day!" << std::endl;
}
```

**niceday.h**

```
#ifndef NICEDAY_H
#define NICEDAY_H

extern __declspec(dllexport) void niceday();

#endif
```

we'll compile `niceday.cpp`

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>g++ -Wall -c -o niceday.obj niceday.cpp
```

Now we'll put these two object files in a static library. `libgreet.lib`

```
ar rcs libgreet.lib hello.obj niceday.obj
```

Another source file and header:

**greeting.cpp**

```
#include "greeting.h"
#include "hello.h"
#include "niceday.h"

void greeting()
{
    hello();
    niceday();
}
```

**greeting.h**

```
#ifndef GREETING_H
#define GREETING_H

extern __declspec(dllexport) void greeting();

#endif
```

Which we'll also compile:

```
g++ -Wall -c -o greeting.obj greeting.cpp
```

Now we'll make a DLL, `libgreeting.dll`, using `greeting.obj` and the static
library `libgreet.lib`:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>g++ -shared -o libgreeting.dll greeting.obj libgreet.lib
```

Here we have a program source file:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "hello.h"
#include "niceday.h"
#include "greeting.h"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    hello();
    niceday();
    std::cout << "I said..." << std::endl;
    greeting();
    return 0;
}
```

which we'll also compile:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>g++ -Wall -c -o  main.obj main.cpp
```

Finally, we'll make a program by linking our `main.obj` with `libgreeting.dll`.
*Only* with `libgreeting.dll`.

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>g++ -o prog main.obj libgreeting.dll
```

Run the program:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>prog
Hello world!
What a nice day!
I said...
Hello world!
What a nice day!
```

All three of the DLL-exported functions, `hello`, `niceday` and `greeting`,
are called. *All that matters*, for this to happen, is that all of them were
declared `__declspec(dllexport)` and all of them were linked into `libgreeting.dll`
*somehow*. As it happens, two of them (`hello`, `niceday`) were linked from a static library and the other (`greeting`) was linked directly from an object file: this doesn't matter.

**And if you're interested...**

Here's how you do the same thing with the Visual Studio 2017 toolchain:

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.4.3
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64'

C:\Users\mikek\source>cd C:\develop\so\scrap

C:\develop\so\scrap>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 16C7-F955

 Directory of C:\develop\so\scrap

16/12/2017  18:31    <DIR>          .
16/12/2017  18:31    <DIR>          ..
16/12/2017  12:41               116 greeting.cpp
16/12/2017  12:42                99 greeting.h
16/12/2017  12:10               109 hello.cpp
16/12/2017  12:12                90 hello.h
16/12/2017  16:21               197 main.cpp
16/12/2017  12:25               117 niceday.cpp
16/12/2017  12:26                96 niceday.h
               7 File(s)            824 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  101,877,473,280 bytes free
```

Compile `hello.cpp`:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>cl /W4 /EHsc /c /Fohello.obj hello.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

hello.cpp
```

Compile `niceday.cpp`:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>cl /W4 /EHsc /c /Foniceday.obj niceday.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

niceday.cpp
```

Make the static library:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>lib /out:libgreet.lib hello.obj niceday.obj
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

Compile `greeting.cpp`:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>cl /W4 /EHsc /c /Fogreeting.obj greeting.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

greeting.cpp
```

Link `libgreeting.dll`:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>link /dll /out:libgreeting.dll greeting.obj libgreet.lib
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

   Creating library libgreeting.lib and object libgreeting.exp
```

Here, as you know, the Microsoft linker creates an *import library* `libgreeting.lib`
(not to be confused with the static library `libgreet.lib`) which is used for
linking `libgreeting.dll` to a program or another DLL.

Compile `main.cpp`:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>cl /W4 /EHsc /c /Fomain.obj main.cpp
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

main.cpp
```

Link our program (using the import library `libgreeting.lib` in lieu of
`libgreeting.dll`):

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>link /out:prog.exe main.obj libgreeting.lib
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

And run:

```
C:\develop\so\scrap>prog
Hello world!
What a nice day!
I said...
Hello world!
What a nice day!
```

**Later**

> If `foo` firstly was compiled without `__declspec(dllexport)` and has a declaration like this `void foo()` when I built B.lib.
>   But when I built C.exe I changed foo's declaration to `__declspec(dllexport) void foo()`. The question is can I still make above happen?

In principle, if you compile an object file with a certain declaration of `foo` in its header file
 and then *change* that declaration subsequently to `#include` the header file in the
 compilation of some other object file, then you are likely to be lying to the compiler in the
 second compilation and when you link these object files into some program or DLL you
 can expect bad things to happen.

In this case however, you can get away with it. In the example above, you
 may first compile, say, `hello.cpp` with the declaration in `hello.h`:

```
extern void hello(void);
```

Later, when you compile `greeting.cpp`, which `#include`s `hello.h`, you
may change the declaration to:

```
extern __declspec(dllexport) void hello(void);
```

with the result that `hello` *will* be DLL_exported when you link `libgreeting.dll`.

The declaration with `__declspec(dllexport)` refines rather than contradicts the
the one without. In linking `libgreeting.dll`, the linker sees a non-DLL-exported reference
to `hello` in `hello.obj` and a DLL-exported reference in `greeting.obj`. It
DLL-exports the symbol because it has seen at least one DLL-exported reference.

Be in no doubt that this is a *hack*.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. One more question, if foo firstly was compiled without `__declspec(dllexport)` and has a declaration like this `void foo()` when I built **B.lib**. But when I built **C.exe** I changed foo's declaration to `__declspec(dllexport) void foo()`.  The question is can I still make above happen?

Comment: Thanks again. BTW, I fixed a previous writing error. See my edit.@Mike Kinghan

Comment: The linker optimizes all objects away, which are not applied inside the dll